# Sandbox payment with PayPal SDK with credit card on android application

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing application with possibility of payments over credit card using PayPal Android SDK. For now - in sandbox. I succeed in making PayPal native payment, as long as payment confirm and refunding. But i cannot make a sandbox payment using credit card. No errors, no logs - after payment confirm activity just closes with no any intent data or so, and returning me to payment method choosing screen. I tried to use some dummy credit card data there, and a real credit card too. Can you help me with that issue? Can a reason be that my account belongs to country with disabled direct card payment (according to documentation, it's enabled for sandbox)? Thank you!

Comment: You should have some sort of logs somewhere that will provide the raw API request and response.  Need to get a look at that.

Comment: yes , this is the point it works fine when i pay with paypal account 
but when i try to pay with card it not even calls the Activity Result while debugging.